# JFileChooser: Cannot select Desktop when Selection Mode is File and Directories

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I ran into an issue with JFileChooser and wanted to see if there is a workaround.

If the JFileChooser is created and the setFileSelectionMode is FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES, when a user clicks a shortcut button on the left (in XP) such as Desktop or My Documents or drop down to Desktop, the field is not placed in the File Name JTextPane. And when clicking the "Select/Accept" button, nothing happens (because isDirectorySelected() returns false for some reason).

Overriding the approveSeletion does not work because the Event Handler function in BasicFileChooser does not call it.

How would I make it so the Desktop can be selected without having to navigate to it manually, but by clicking the shortcut on the left?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you double click "Desktop", don't choose any file, and click "Accept"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows, the desktop is not backed by any file in the file system - it's a shell namespace.  So there really isn't anything that JFileChooser *could* return to you.  Yes, I know that there is a folder that contains the desktop for the user - but remember that the desktop actually displays as a composite of the user's desktop and the All Users desktop folder - plus other things that are added by the shell but not part of any folder (like the trash bin).  So returning a File object that represents the 'desktop' is pretty much a non-starter.

Long and short:  Ask yourself why you need to do this - chances are that you are going to wind up deep into native code territory, dealing with namespace PIDLs and all sorts of nastiness that you may not want to get into (for the life of me, I cannot understand why M$ had to make this stuff so amazingly difficult to use)...

Here's an intro to Windows shell namespaces so you'll have a feel for what's involved:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Is this the same for "My Documents"

Comment: Navigating is also really weird too.  If I click a shortcut to those folders, then it works.  Strangely enough, if I go to desktop, then inside a folder in my desktop, then pop back up, the File Name path stays the same as it was before.  And the reason for saving to the desktop is for ease of use.  I save tons of stuff to my desktop for quick testing and access with the intent of eventually deleting.

Answer (score 2):

Found the following code in the BasicFileChooserUI:

```
if (fc.getFileSelectionMode() == JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES 
&&  fc.getFileSystemView().isFileSystem(dir)) {
    setFileName(dir.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

So it looks like "special folders" are purposely ignored. The code is in a private method so it would be hard to create you own UI.

As a hack you might be able to add a PropertyChangeListener to the file chooser:

```
public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent e)
{
    String prop = e.getPropertyName();

    if (JFileChooser.DIRECTORY_CHANGED_PROPERTY.equals(prop))
    {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = (JFileChooser)e.getSource();
        File currentDirectory = (File)e.getNewValue();

        String directory = currentDirectory.toString();

        if (directory.endsWith("Desktop")
        ||  directory.endsWith("My Documents"))
        {
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

            if (selectedFile == null || ! selectedFile.equals(currentDirectory))
            {
                fileChooser.removePropertyChangeListener( this );
                fileChooser.setSelectedFile( currentDirectory );
                fileChooser.addPropertyChangeListener( this );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code kind of works. When Desktop is selected, the "My documents" folder gets displayed but Desktop IS the selected file because the user can then click Select and it returns teh path to desktop.  If "My Documents" is selected, it navigates to its parent directory.  I have a feeling that its getting flagged in the setSelectedFile function and attempts to display its parent directory.